# Why was the warning to add content description to image views and image button removed in AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, accessibility

When building layouts in android, if you use an `ImageView` or an `ImageButton` without adding a content description, then you would get a warning telling you to add a content description to the views with `AppCompatImageView` and `AppCompatImageButton` that warning is no longer available. I thought this is because the implementation for `AppCompatImageView`  has a default content description based on the content of the view but talk back still reads it as an "un labelled button", why was the warning removed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This lint rule is designed to work on specific widget types. Currently, this rule is checking only `ImageView` and `ImageButton` widgets. The lack of warning for `AppCompat` widgets is because they have never added them to the element list.

The [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/5289a6f/lint/libs/lint_checks/src/com/android/tools/lint/checks/AccessibilityDetector.java#87) of the current implementation shows that it is applied only to `ImageView` and `ImageButton`.

```java
public Collection<String> getApplicableElements() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            IMAGE_BUTTON,
            IMAGE_VIEW
    );
}
```

I have filled a [bug on the Android issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134134844) to request them to add `AppCompatImageView` and `AppCompatImageButton` to this lint rule. You may star the issue to convey your support.